# How to speed up Winforms ListView item removal?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance, listview

I already use `listView.BeginUpdate()` and `listView.EndUpdate()`, but it still takes like 10 seconds when I delete for example 100 items out of 25k.

Any ideas, tricks to make it faster?

EDIT:

```
this.listView.BeginUpdate();
for (int i = this.listView.CheckedItems.Count - 1; i > -1; --i)
{
    this.listView.CheckedItems[i].Remove();
}
this.listView.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Do you really need to load 25k items at one time? How about pagination or loading by scrolling?

Comment: Show me the code, I can delete 100 items in milliseconds. Just checked the code and I do it by binding.

Comment: The user can scroll back and forth and randomly see the list sections, so I don't know how else to optimize for this.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: I added the code, that's all I am using.

Comment: +1 [Here is a list of the alternatives](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/170900/How-to-Delete-Selected-Items-of-ListView-and-ListB), how depressing there isn't a RemoveRange. Perhaps to reach a solution you could explain more about the scenario of users scrolling back and forth and then we could give you GUI idea's to avoid this situation as @allentranks mentions.

Comment: Are you handling any events that has to do with item changes?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I know it's really a shame these common controls are very slow. Basically the app is all about this list view and the users have to go through all these items until they have removed all items. So since this is a boring task, they often just randomly scroll to another point in the list and work there, but this happens probably several times in 15 mins. It's hard to describe, but that's about it :)

Comment: I hated the slowness of WinForms. Result? Ended up doing C++.

Comment: @Mehrdad, what control framework did you use?

Comment: @JoanVenge: Using ATL with WTL right now, it's quite a bit more painful than Windows Forms but it seems to be worth it.

Comment: Btw you might want to try out the "virtual mode" of ListView.

Answer (score 3):

You can start your optimizations from here:

```
List<int> toRemove = new List<int>();

foreach (ListViewItem item in this.listView.Items)
{
    if (item.Checked) // check other remove conditions here
        toRemove.Add(item.Index);
}

/* sort indices descending, so you'll remove items with higher indices first
   and they will not be shifted when you remove items with lower indices */
toRemove.Sort((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x));
/* in this specific case you can simply use toRemove.Reverse(); 
   or iterate thru toRemove in reverse order
   because it is already sorted ascending.
   But you might want to force sort it descending in some other cases.
*/

this.listView.BeginUpdate();

foreach (int itemIndex in toRemove)
    this.listView.Items.RemoveAt(itemIndex); // use RemoveAt when possible. It's much faster with large collections

this.listView.EndUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

The ListView will trigger an event  for every single item that is removed from the list. You could try to avoid that by clearing the entire ListView and then adding at once a new list of items, which is stripped of the 100 items you wanted to remove.
This would trigger only a handful of events.

Answer (score 0):

That's because each time you remove element from Items, ListView has to find that item ([walking the list to do so](http://fiddler2.com/blog/blog/2013/05/08/building-a-faster-fiddler-with-justtrace-and-justdecompile)) and refresh CheckedItems collection (which iterates all remaining items again) so complexity is O^2.

The easiest approach is to cache SelectedIndices and use listItem.Items.RemoveAt():

```
var selectedIndices = listView.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().Reverse().ToList();
listView.BeginUpdate();
foreach (var index in selectedIndices) {
    listView.Items.RemoveAt(index);
}
listView.EndUpdate();
```

If you don't want to use the Cast<> extension method, you can replace the first line with:

```
List<int> oToDelete = new List<int>(SelectedIndices.Count);
foreach (int iX in SelectedIndices)
{
   oToDelete.Add(iX);
}
oToDelete.Reverse();
```

Comment: Thanks but listView doesn't seem to have a RemoveAt method.

Comment: Ok I found it, it was inside items but the cast crashes.